# Kill Several Processes In VB?

Tags: .net, vb.net, process, kill, kill-process

I currently have the following up in VS 2010

```
        Dim myProcess() As Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("calc")

    For Each myKill As Process In myProcess
        myKill.Kill()
```

However I cannot seem to get it to kill more than one process.
Example I've tried

```
("calc",mspaint")
("calc,mspaint")
("calc"),("mspaint")
```

Any ideas?
Thanks for your time/support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote from MSDN documentation of [GetProcessByName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessesbyname.aspx):

> Creates an array of new Process components and associates them with
>   the existing process resources that all share the specified process
>   name.

You can't pass an array of arguments to it.Instead,you can get all the processes using the [GetProcesses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f3ys1f9.aspx) method,iterate over all processes and check if its name match one of the names you want:

```
 Dim procs = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses().Where((Function(p) p.ProcessName = "calc" Or p.ProcessName = "mspaint"))
            For Each p As Process In procs
                p.Kill()
            Next
```

Non-LINQ way:

```
 For Each p As Process In Process.GetProcesses()
            If p.ProcessName = "calc" Or p.ProcessName = "mspaint" Then
                p.Kill()
            End If
        Next
```

Comment: Thanks :) That works. But what I wanted to kill any more than two? (i'll work on it myself in the mean-time)

Comment: NVM last comment, I did this         For Each p As Process In Process.GetProcesses()
            If p.ProcessName = "calc" Or p.ProcessName = "mspaint" Or p.ProcessName = "pidgin" Then
                p.Kill()
            End If
        Next